# Implementing PencilKit with PDFKit

Tags: ios, pdf, ios13, blurry, pencilkit

My app shows PDF files using the **PDFKit** and lets users make annotations on pdf files through my own code using `UIKit` and `CoreGraphics` frameworks. Since I would like to use the **PencilKit** framework to make annotations better, I’m in the process to implement the `PencilKit` framework but I’ve found some issues which I am stuck with.

What I did is to add a `PKCanvasView` over the `DocumentView` of a PDFView. In essence, it works fine, I can annotate using the tools of the `PencilKit` and I can navigate through the pages of the PDF.

The problem appears when I zoom-in on a PDF page. Since the `PKCanvasView` is not zooming itself as it’s inside the `DocumentView`, the ink annotations appear pixelated. The `PKCanvasView` is not redrawing its content with a new scale because its zoom has not changed and updating the `contentScaleFactor` to make the drawing sharper doesn’t work.

Another problem is, in some way related to the previous one, since the app fits each PDF page to use all the screen, this makes the zoom of the `UIScrollView`, which contains the `DocumentView` of the PDFView, vary in function of the size of the PDF page. This makes that if I open a PDF which has small pages and another with large pages, in terms of size (Width x Height), I will see the width of the lines of the inking tool with different sizes even if I have selected the smallest line width on the `PKToolPicker` for both files.

So I wonder if it could be possible to add a `PKCanvasView` and a PDFView separately to a `UIViewController’s` view, so they both have the same `superview`, with the same ContentSize and maximum/minimum zoom level and, when panning and zooming on the `PKCanvasView`, the PDFView does too.

Anyway, if there's a workaround I would be happy to know. ;)

Comment: any luck with that?

Comment: Also in the same position. Everything works except the minimum stroke width is too large

Comment: Did you find that iOS14 breaks the gesture recognizer? Where did you set it?

Comment: any solution ????